# Why is $1/n^{1/3}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I thought because $p<1$ it would be divergent, but apparently not. Why is that?

Comment: Hmm, what is $p$?

Comment: what is $p$? Maybe you mean $\sum n^{-1/3}$?

Comment: Are you talking about the sequence $\dfrac{1}{n^{1/3}}$ which converges to $0$ or the series $\sum\dfrac{1}{n^{1/3}}$ which diverges?

Comment: Why has this got so many downvotes? It looks like a perfectly valid question, albeit one arising from a misunderstanding.

Comment: @Billy we still don't know if it is a series or a sequence. The $p$ is undefined. There is no introduction and people are answering supposing it were a series without knowing it.

Comment: @AmireBendjeddou So? Help the OP to fix their question instead of just bashing the downvote button. Are you here to help, or not?

Comment: @Billy Yes i'm here to help , that's why i asked the OP to be clear (still no response).I usually never downvote a question , but if i do it's because i think i might be able to help but it's just not clear what the question really is. But your are right , we are here to help not to judge!

Comment: @AmireBendjeddou Ah, sorry, I didn't see that you were one of the above (helpful) commenters. But yes, I think that comments of your sort are good (the OP might not have responded because only 2 hours have passed!), and downvotes are kind of unproductive. I tend to find they drive new users away feeling attacked, rather than encouraging them to ask better questions.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $n^{1/3}\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. And your sequence is $$n^{-1/3}=\frac{1}{n^{1/3}}$$

**ADD** It seems you're confusing things. For **any** $p>0$, $$n^{-p}\to 0$$

**However** $$\sum_{n\geqslant 1}n^{-p}$$ converges only when $p>1$.

Answer (score 2):

The *sequence* $\{n^{-1/3}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is convergent, since $n^{-1/3} = \frac{1}{n^{1/3}}$ tends to $0$ as $n$ grows. The series (i.e. sequence of partial sums) resulting in

$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty n^{-1/3}$$

is divergent, however.

Answer (score 2):

You, certainly, know the series $\sum (1/n)$ and know that it is divergent. There is  a nice approach in which we can test the divergence or convergence. That is the [Quotient Test or Limit comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests). According to it, if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_n}{v_n}=A\neq0, ~~\text{or}~~ A=\infty$$ then $\sum u_n$ and $\sum v_n$ have the same destiny. Here, take $\sum v_n=\sum (1/n)$.

Comment: You're up *very* early! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Oh not that very early but Sun is getting up. Have you had a good day Amy? :-)

Comment: Any day I "see" you is a good day, @Babak!

Comment: @BabakS. +1 for no reason! :-D

Answer (score 1):

By the inequality
$$\frac{1}{n}\leq \frac{1}{n^{1/3}}$$
we conclude that the serie $\displaystyle\sum_n \frac{1}{n^{1/3}}$ is divergent .

Answer (score 0):

The series $\displaystyle \sum_{n\geqslant 1} n^{-p}$ converges for $p>1$, if you are curious to why, you could search up Cauchy Condensation Test or even the Integral test.